# Battery slowly draining on AC power then laptop (running Ubuntu) drastically slows down when it hits 30%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, battery, battery-life

So all of a sudden my AC charger is not able to keep my battery charging when I'm using my laptop anymore. My Laptop is an Acer Aspire 5 A515-51G-72DB  and I bought it brand new 5 years ago.

It slowly drops down the battery level from 100% until it hits 30% then it stops dropping the battery level but instead the laptop becomes really slow and I have to suspend it and let it charge again.

Some people told me that this issue is caused when your battery has completed all its cycles (or something like that) and then the OS detects it and sets the power settings to power saving.

So I decided to replace my old battery with a brand new one but as you can imagine it didn't work out and I'm still facing the same problem with the new battery. Any ideas why this is happening?

My OS is Ubuntu 21.04 and I'm currently upgrading it to. 21.10 to see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details: What is the exact make and model of the laptop? How long have you owned it? Is it new or used? Because what you say “…battery has completed all its cycles…”that sounds like a dead or dying batter to me.

Comment: If a brand new battery behaves the same way then it's probably the charger. Can you try it with another power brick of the same type?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I've edited the question, thank you. But the question here is that even with a brand new battery the behavior is the same.

Comment: @AlexandreLutosa Sounds like a power plan is set to turn on at 30% in the OS, configured to slow the CPU to a certain percentage. Separate from the former, laptops don't run off the battery while plugged in, unless they're exceeding the wattage of the charger due to a discrete GPU the charger isn't rated to power at max usage _(before replacing a battery/charger, run the built-in BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics on them, accessible from the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot screen or within the BIOS/UEFI firmware, which will tell you health of the battery/charger and max capacity of battery)_.